# Check RTSP URI during onCreate in Android

Tags: android, uri, rtsp

I'm creating a fairly simple Android app for work that will plug a URI into the system video player so that users can easily watch the RTSP stream that we are sending from our Wowza server.

In general, I basically just have a play button that calls:

```
Uri myURI = Uri.parse("rtsp://ipaddress:1935/path/myStream");    
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myURI);
startActivity(intent);
```

but we don't stream from this URI 24/7 and I would like to change the behavior during onCreate so that it will validate the URI before drawing the button, giving me the opportunity to give the user visual feedback that the stream isn't live and save us unneeded support emails.

I've looked at the Uri and URI classes to see if there was a method that I could call to check the URI but nothing seems to really exist. Other URI related questions seem to refer to local files so the dev can just check a file, but I don't think that would work for a live stream. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to open a plain client socket connection to the RTSP server hostname/port and then post a RTSP OPTIONS request. 
If the server responds with a "RTSP/1.0 200 OK", it means the streaming service is up, otherwise it's down.

I wrote a quick and dirty sample RTSP check and tested it out. Feel free to adapt it to your needs:

**Update** handling UI operations
In your activity class, create these fields:

```
private static final int MESSAGE_RTSP_OK = 1;
private static final int MESSAGE_RTSP_ERROR = -1;

private Handler handler;
```

in your onCreate method, add:

```
    handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what){
                case MESSAGE_RTSP_OK:
                    //show_player(); 
                    // implement ui operation here
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_RTSP_ERROR:
                    //show_error();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Then run this sample code:
**Updated rtsp check code**

```
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket client = new Socket("a1352.l1857053128.c18570.g.lq.akamaistream.net", 554);
                OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
                os.write("OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0\n".getBytes());
                os.write("CSeq: 1\n\n".getBytes());
                os.flush();

                //NOTE: it's very important to end any rtsp request with \n\n (two new lines). The server will acknowledge that the request ends there and it's time to send the response back.

                BufferedReader br =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                        new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream())));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String responseLine = null;

                while (null != (responseLine = br.readLine()))
                    sb.append(responseLine);
                String rtspResponse = sb.toString();
                if(rtspResponse.startsWith("RTSP/1.0 200 OK")){
                    // RTSP SERVER IS UP!!
                     handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_RTSP_OK).sendToTarget();
                } else {
                    // SOMETHING'S WRONG

                    handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_RTSP_ERROR).sendToTarget();
                }
                Log.d("RTSP reply" , rtspResponse);
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // NETWORK ERROR such as Timeout 
                e.printStackTrace();

                handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_RTSP_ERROR).sendToTarget();
            }

        }
    }.start();`
```

For this test I picked the public NASA TV rtsp server: `rtsp://a1352.l1857053128.c18570.g.lq.akamaistream.net:554`

The code sends the following rtsp request:

`OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1`

And receives the following response:

`RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: QTSS-Akamai/6.0.3 (Build/526.3; Platform/Linux; Release/Darwin; )
Cseq: 1
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD`

If you are looking for more complex checks, feel free to dive into the rtsp protocol documentation and enhance the code per your own needs: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Honestly, this is a lot more complicated than what I was hoping to get into. I tested this thread and it doesn't seem to work. It makes sense if the server is actually down and you get no response but  the thread ultimately crashes the app because I'm trying to modify the view heirarchy from outside of the main thread, which is illegal and only the main thread can call setContentView. I'll have to see if I can do something from the server-side that will make this easier on the Android client.

Comment: That crash is because you are not allowed to perform UI operations from a non-UI threads (and vice versa). You need to fire an event from the non-ui thread via a handler and implement the actual ui operation where the event is intercepted (that would be an UI thread operation as the handler runs on the UI thread). See https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: I updated the sample code to dispatch from background thread to UI thread, so you'll need to only trigger the UI changes in the appropriate handler switch case.

Comment: So I got this working with the NASA RTSP server but it is incredibly slow. It took the phone almost a minute to draw the interface while it was waiting for a response, which is unacceptable from a user's perspective. I appreciate the help and it might be useful for someone else but I don't think I can use this for my purposes.

Comment: The responsive practice would be to show up at least a loader/spinner while doing the background operations as well as adding the possibility to cancel the heavy action. On my PC internet connection using emulator, the check is instant, but on 3G/GPRS network it may be sloppy. But in case it is that sloppy to take a minute to do this simple check - I doubt the video will actually play at all. If you would like to limit the check time, you can set up socket timeouts so it fails when the preconfigured wait time is elapsed.

Comment: Hey @Markus I am trying this code with my sjcam(ip camera) but its not working. It always give Unable to resolve host.

Comment: Hey @Spartan, did you connect the camera and the client app on the same network and are you trying to connect to the camera's IP assigned by the network router?

Comment: @Markus I connected app with camera through wifi and its streaming rtsp video but ping is not working at all.

Comment: The issue you are experiencing is not code related. Please feel free to start a new question on your specific set-up, with all possible information. Let me know of your post and I'll get back to you.