# How do I check if an RTSP URL is streaming?

Tags: android, rtsp, vitamio

I'm receiving an external RTSP url. When I try to play the url, the server responds with

```
E/Vitamio[4.2.6][Player]: [rtsp @ 0xde14c000] method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Not Found
```

This seems to indicate that the stream was not found. When I try to play the same url using vlc, the stream works. I'm guessing the Stream isn't ready. I need to write code to check if the stream is live. I refered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013233/check-rtsp-uri-during-oncreate-in-android) question which refers to checking the server but I'm not sure about how to do it for an absolute stream url of the form

```
rtsp://www.test.com:1935/live/test
```

Comment: you can test without android device if you install java/rtsp client on PC that has curl. use Curl to request the stream and look at curl's stdout using -vvv switch . example : http://snipplr.com/view/63341/youtube-rtsp-cli-request--audio-track-only-p2/

Comment: @RobertRowntree your link is dead.....

Comment: -v2$ curl -s -D - http://snipplr.com/view/63341/youtube-rtsp-cli-request--audio-track-only-p2/ -o /dev/null


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 04 Feb 2017 17:19:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
....